# Android ADB shell commands: Mount host PC folder?

Tags: android, shell, adb, mount

Hope this isn't too much of an amateur/moron question: I'm trying to replace most ringtones and alarms (Dell Streak 5 (2.2.2 rooted)) with a few of my own pet sounds.
For reasons I won't bother you with, I can't use an SD card, so my .ogg replacements need be transferred straight from my PC to their respective default folders under /system/media/audio/ .

ADB push and pull commands don't seem to accept widlcards (which is a pain) but anyway, despite setting the system folder to rw, I get 'permission denied' when I tediously attempt to pull or push files one by one.

But I should be able to rm and cp interactively from ADB's shell # prompt, with simple Unix commands to transfer groups of files between the /system/media/audio folders and my Windows PC. But to do this I presumably need to mount my PC source folder, and I have no idea how to do this.

I'd be grateful for any info or ideas...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have root access on the phone.  My advice as a programmer would be to

1) Write a program to do this...

or just do it the easy way haha.  Try this (your device must be rooted):

1. adb shell into your device using `$> adb shell`
2. move to the local folder using `$> cd /data/local`
3. Now create a directory for your tones with `$> mkdir my_tones` - this shouldn't require su
4. Next you must push your .ogg files from your computer to the /data/local/my_tones folder
5. Now you can become su user with `$> su`
6. Now you should be able to copy the files from the /data/local/my_tones directory to where ever it is you would like them.

Hope this helps.